# Python Heap Implementation

Tags: python, heap

I made this snippet for reviewing my DS textbook.
Is it okay to write iterative loops in function `_upheap` and `_downheap`?
Any other suggestions or feedbacks are welcome. 
Thanks.

```
# heap.py
# by kidkkr
# Mar-14-2017, 07:29PM

class Heap:
    __slots__ = '_data'

    def __init__(self):
        self._data = []

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._data)

    def isEmpty(self):
        return len(self) == 0

    def add(self, item):
        self._data.append(item)
        self._upheap(len(self) - 1)

    def del_min(self):
        self._swap(0, len(self) - 1)
        res = self._data.pop()
        self._downheap(0)
        return res

    def _left(self, j):
        return 2*j + 1

    def _hasLeft(self, j):
        return self._left(j) < len(self)

    def _right(self, j):
        return 2*j + 2

    def _hasRight(self, j):
        return self._right(j) < len(self)

    def _parent(self, j):
        return (j - 1)/2

    def _swap(self, i, j):
        self._data[i], self._data[j] = \
            self._data[j], self._data[i]

    def _upheap(self, j):
        while j > 0 and self._data[j] < self._data[self._parent(j)]:
            self._swap(j, self._parent(j))
            j = self._parent(j)

    def _downheap(self, j):
        while j < len(self):
            if self._hasLeft(j):
                smallChild = self._left(j)
                if self._hasRight(j) and \
                    self._data[smallChild] > self._data[self._right(j)]:
                    smallChild = self._right(j)
                if self._data[j] > self._data[smallChild]:
                    self._swap(j, smallChild)
                    j = smallChild
                else:
                    break
            else:
                break


if __name__ == "__main__":
### Test Codes
    a = Heap()
    a.add(21)
    a.add(28)
    a.add(16)
    a.add(9)
    a.add(14)
    a.add(21)
    a.add(26)
    a.add(33)
    a.add(22)
    a.add(6)
    a.add(22)
    print(a.del_min())
    print(a.del_min())
    print(a.del_min())
    print(a.del_min())
    print(a.del_min())
    print(a.del_min())
    print(a.del_min())
    print(a.del_min())
    print(a.del_min())
    print(a.del_min())
    print(a.del_min())
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your method `isEmpty` is not needed at all. First, none of your code uses it. Second, if you were to keep it, you should turn it's logic around and rename it to `__bool__`, this way, `if heap` automatically works and is `True` if the heap is not empty. But third, if no `__bool__` method exists, Python already calls `len(obj) != 0` to determine an object's truthiness, so it is already supplied by defining `__len__`.

As a second point, you should not mix naming conventions. You currently use both `lower_case` and `camelCase` for your​ method names. [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), Python's official style-guide, recommends using `lower_case`.

You don't need the line-continuation in here, the line is already shorter than 80 characters:

```
    def _swap(self, i, j):
        self._data[i], self._data[j] = self._data[j], self._data[i]
```

Some [`docstrings`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) describing what your methods do and what they expect as inputs/what they return, would also be really good.

I would rename your method `del_min` to `pop_min`, because it returns the removed element and not just deletes it.